# How to migrate the custom laravel admin panel code in laravel voyager?

Tags: laravel, voyager

i' facing the problem to merge the code in laravel voyager. i've created the admin panel, client panel, publisher panel section in laravel. but due to some reason, i'm migrating the all code in laravel voyager.  laravel voyager is a admin panel to provide CRUD, BREAD. is it possible ? how i can implement this ? Below i attached the screenshot of directory structure.  Thanks in advance.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Comment: aww, man install phpStorm...

Comment: i want to place the code inside laravel voyager.

Comment: @AdamKozlowski, can you suggest me how to migrate the code inside laravel voyager ? is it possible ?

Comment: i guess you need to make own integration, there is no migrator